# Aligning edittext to match a full-screened parent bottom

Tags: android, android-edittext

How do I make edit text align a full screened parent bottom.

My layout seem to misbehave plz I need some help

Comment: what parent layout are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Add `android:gravity="bottom"` to your parent